# Facebook Likes disappearing from page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am having issues with Facebook "Likes" disappearing from some of my website pages ( http://www.ufunded.com/campaigns/lisamom-foundation ). When I run the page URL through the Facebook Debugger, I get the following warning:

`Mismatch og:url and canonical url: og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html.`

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ufunded.com%2Fcampaigns%2Fgametime-salsa

However, when I view the source code of the page, all the links are consistent. What could be causing this issue? Also, could the indicated link issue cause my likes to disappear?

Comment: At this moment, the linked source's line 50 says: `<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.ufunded.com/campaigns' />` while the og:url is `http://www.ufunded.com/campaigns/lisamom-foundation` the canonical version has one segment less.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://www.ufunded.com/campaigns/gametime-salsa)-link at the bottom shows that there are the following tags in the document:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ufunded.com/campaigns/gametime-salsa">

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.ufunded.com/campaigns">
```

And as the debug tool says, these point to different URLs.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ufunded.com/wp-content/uploads/campaign_uploads/1399534_2012.09.27 - Gametime Salsa - Bryce Conway -106.jpg">
```

If you are using spaces in (image) URLs, you should URL-encode them properly in places like this.

Comment: That was problem! Thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake. I can't believe I didn't see that. Its definitely a cold, rainy Monday.

Answer (score 0):

add dash / ,or add .html at the end of href of link rel="canonical" , it will work.

For example:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://toidangtin.com/tp-ha-noi/do-gia-dung-san-vuon/can-mua/can-mua-ti-vi-loa-amply-may-vi-tinh-tai-nha-co-quan-thanh-ly-cu-moi-ke-ca-cu-hong-291"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://toidangtin.com/tp-ha-noi/do-gia-dung-san-vuon/can-mua/can-mua-ti-vi-loa-amply-may-vi-tinh-tai-nha-co-quan-thanh-ly-cu-moi-ke-ca-cu-hong-291"/>
```

The above does not work and Facebook Debuger give this warning: "og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html."

but after i add /

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://toidangtin.com/tp-ha-noi/do-gia-dung-san-vuon/can-mua/can-mua-ti-vi-loa-amply-may-vi-tinh-tai-nha-co-quan-thanh-ly-cu-moi-ke-ca-cu-hong-291/"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://toidangtin.com/tp-ha-noi/do-gia-dung-san-vuon/can-mua/can-mua-ti-vi-loa-amply-may-vi-tinh-tai-nha-co-quan-thanh-ly-cu-moi-ke-ca-cu-hong-291/"/>
```

it works.